# How do I get a element to appear/disappear once HTML document height is adjusted, in JQuery?

Tags: jquery

See code below

Objective: If the browser window has a vertical scroll, show #scroll-top...else hide #scroll-top.

Problem: I have elements on my page that I can toggle therefore adjusting the page height, hence affecting if the browser scrollbar is visible or not.

Question: How do I get #scroll-top to disappear if I collapse/toggle all elements on the page & appear once I expand all elements?

```
var hContent = $("body").height(); 
var hWindow = $(window).height(); 

if(hContent>hWindow) {
    $('#scroll-top').fadeIn(250);    
}
else {
    $('#scroll-top').fadeOut(250);
}
```

Any help is Greatly Appreciated, Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just wrap your example code in a function and call it whenever you toggle your elements to determine if you need to show or hide `#scroll-top`:

```
function ToggleScrollTop() {
   var hContent = $("body").height(); 
   var hWindow = $(window).height(); 

   if(hContent>hWindow) {
       $('#scroll-top').fadeIn(250);    
   }
   else {
       $('#scroll-top').fadeOut(250);
   }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function scrollTopCheck() {

      if(hContent>hWindow) {
        $('#scroll-top').fadeIn(250);    
      }
      else {
          $('#scroll-top').fadeOut(250);
      }
    }  




setInterval(500, scrollTopCheck); //this would call scrollTopCheck function every 1/2 second
```

However its better to define a callback on $.toggle(*callback*)

```
$('.elementsToToggle').toggle(scrollTopCheck);
```